# Install tile over engineered hardwood

Tags: laminate-floor, ceramic-tile

So I’ve looked through a lot of similar questions, but I haven’t seen this exact one, maybe that’s a bad sign. I live in a rented apartment with a very small kitchen that has this annoying fake hardwood, I think it’s laminate. I wish I could install tile. Is there someway that I could install tile over the laminate hardwood? There’s no clearance or door issue, as long as I don’t damage anything or improve it, my landlord/management will be just fine. Is it possible to put down plywood over the laminate hardwood, then Ditra, then tile over that?

Comment: That's a lot of expense for a rental... and I'd be surprised if the landlord was really happy with permanent modifications to the building being done by anyone but an (insured and permitted) pro. You _might_ be able to get away with a snap-together "floating floor" system; most of those I've seen try to look like wood not there might be some which try to look like tile...

Comment: If it's crappy laminate, then it shouldn't be that hard to remove.  Then you can add your plywood and ditra directly to the subfloor.  Won't have unnecessary additional height or have a weird unreliable layer under your tile.  That said, that does sound like a weirdly expensive project to undertake in a rental.

Comment: I agree that it's an odd strategy, but the answer depends on the exact nature of the existing floor. If there's a felt or rubber underlayment, for example, it's a no-go. Please provide more information in your question.

Answer (score 1):

use large format vinyl tiles over the laminate instead. The high quality versions will feel close enough to tile in a rental

Answer (score 0):

Wood or hardwood floors move/flex. That would not go well with tiles. They will crack.

Usually one would use a cement board aka backer-board under the tiles. That would add to the total thickness so better check that.

To avoid trouble, get a written permit from landlord.